# How to make firebase not create a new user for Google OAuth on sign in?

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

On sign in using firebase's Google OAuth provider, it automatically creates an account for the user if one does not exist. Is there a way to not create an account and return an error on sign in?

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)

Answer (score 2):

When you call the sign-in method, it will create an account for the user if it does not exist.

If you want to check if an account exists or not, you would have to perform the "Login with Google" OAuth flow yourself (without the Firebase SDK) and then use a Cloud function to check if a user with the email exists (you might also have to maintain a list of users (their emails) in Firestore). If not, then you can create a new account with the access token you received.